# User downvoted random questions and answers of mine

Tags: support, chat, down-votes

A specific user voted random questions and answers by mine down and made other people do the same to what was otherwise good content. The reason? He didn't like me and wanted me to conform to his ideologies most likely. Anyway, this led to a not-accessible chat for me.

Well, read the Javascript and Sandbox room for more.

How can acts like this be disputed or resolved? Should I email the Stack Exchange team?

Comment: "made other people do the same"...do you really believe this?

Comment: 1) How do you know it was that user? Can you prove it was actually that specific user that downvoted you? (Voting is anonymous; not even the moderators can see who voted on a particular question.) 2) If the voter simply engaged in downvoting you maliciously, there's an automated script that will reverse it return the reputation to you; it runs every night. 3) This has been asked before. See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), or search this site for "serial voting".

Comment: @KenWhite from this message in the chat mostly http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16374841#16374841

Comment: @NickStauner yes because one question is downvote more than 1 time

Comment: @dondom all of this is very one sided.  there are no undeleted messages by you so there is no way to tell what you might have said to tick him off in the first place.  I'm not saying downvoting to keep someone from chatting is justified, just pointing out that high rep users don't generally pick people at random to downvote to prevent from chatting, so you must have done *something*

Comment: @dondom: The transcript is meaningless, because you deleted your side of the discussion. It does appear there was some implied encouragement to downvote to stop you from chatting, but if you remove your side of the content it's pretty difficult to feel sorry for you. If you were being abusive or disruptive, they may have had reason to want you out of chat. Your removing your part of the conversation makes it seem like you have something to hide; it makes it very hard to be sympathetic toward you. If there was indeed serial downvoting by a single user, it will be reversed as I said.

Comment: messages were not delete by me ..

Comment: We do monitor voting patterns. See the duplicate target for more info. If that doesn't resolve things to your satisfaction, please email us via the "contact us" form at the bottom of any page.

Comment: Dear @AnnaLear, quick question about [your edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/231369/1): any idea why [I had to write the original title and support tag back into my suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/231369/revisions)? They were visible on the question itself after your edit, but they didn't appear in the edit fields...[tag:bug]-report-worthy?

Comment: @NickStauner Not sure what you're talking about. Didn't see any suggested edits on the post when I was editing it (and wouldn't have been able to do my edit without reviewing yours first anyway).

Comment: @NickStauner I did destroy (that is, hard-delete) the original revision of the post, which may have been the issue if you started your suggestion before that. Not bug-report worthy since destroyed revisions are super-rare.

Comment: @AnnaLear, I began my suggested edit after yours had been completed. The edit page had blank fields for the title and tags. Hence the title in my suggested edit appears highlighted in green, as does the support tag, since I had to enter both back in (that is, I assume if I hadn't, it might not have preserved the title and support tag). If this is still a rare destruction-related issue, I won't bother reporting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to address this specific situation given what I said in [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231369/user-downvoted-random-questions-and-answers-by-mine#comment760340_231369).  We are only getting 1 side of a story, so it is unfair to judge anyone for any actions.  The transcript you linked contains virtually no posts by you (aside from a few quoted replies), so there is zero context to be able to judge anyone's actions.  High rep users do misbehave, but so do low rep users.

But in general, disputes between specific users cannot be discussed in a community forum such as this one.

If you feel you have been mistreated by a specific user, you are best taking any issues directly to the Stack Exchange team by contacting them using the [*contact us*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer of every page.

Be warned that they **can** see the deleted posts (as can moderators) so anything you might have done that you (or someone else) deleted will be easily visible to them, and anything you might have done to become the target of any user's downvotes would be part of any discussion.

All this being said though, a single user targeting a specific user by downvoting their posts is against the voting guidelines and generally against the rules.  Voting is supposed to be for a post and not directed at a user.  You might want to review [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), but the short version is there is an automated check to detect and serial voting, if it indeed happened.